# How to serve static files with apache on openshift official python cartridge?

Tags: apache-2.2, python, openshift-online-2, static-files

I have scalable openshift online app with official python-2.7 cartridge. By default everything is served with mod_wsgi handler. How do I configure my app and/or Apache to serve some static files in my repo (like images, css and javascript) with Apache instead of python backend?

Comment: You mean _other than_ putting them in `/static`?

Comment: Michael Hampton, Putting files in `/static` doesn't help. As I said, with official python-2.7 cartridge *everything* is served via wsgi handler.

Comment: If you wanted to escape from the short comings of the OpenShift mod_wsgi setup, you could always consider doing what is described in http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/01/using-alternative-wsgi-servers-with.html This uses mod_wsgi-express and it is trivial to have it also host static files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just figured it out by examining the [cartridge source](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-python/usr/versions/shared/etc/conf.d/openshift.conf.erb). Files in `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/static` folder are served by Apache directly. Its completely undocumented though, and may break in the future.

Comment: I think the `/static` folder is the one you should use. Looking at the linked source, the `/wsgi/static` folder seems to be an alias for it.